# django-cmz - cmsplugin_zinnia - error template 404.html/500.html

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to set the default Django error handler for the django-cms and cmsplugin-zinnia, but for some reason I am not able to ovveride it.

At the moment each time I type in non-existent URL I get the default error message:

*"Zinnia's Blog
Just another Zinnia weblog.
/ Error 500 "*

**My settings.py configuration is:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.comments',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'cms',
'mptt',
'south',
'cms.plugins.text',
'cms.plugins.picture',
'cms.plugins.link',
'cms.plugins.file',
'cms.plugins.snippet',
'cms.plugins.googlemap',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'sekizai',
'menus',
'filer',
'djangocms_utils',
'simple_translation',
'tagging',
'zinnia',
'cmsplugin_zinnia',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'cmsplugin_contact',
```

)

**and url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
```

)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'sitemap.xml/$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

any suggestions ?

Cheers,

Comment: Maybe something wrong with the url order: *try* `urlpatterns += patterns(...)` in `if settings.DEBUG:`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve your issue, by creating your own 404.html and 500.html templates.

Regards